# Step Up DC DC [12 to 300] using MAX1771 Chip

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost

I am trying to build my first circuit following the information posted here
[12v to 300v Boost Converter - Ideal Inductor for 9kOhm load](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/73342/12v-to-300v-boost-converter-ideal-inductor-for-9kohm-load)
I tried to answer there before opening this new topic,but I need at least 10 reputation....so,my goal is the same,obtaining 300 Vdc from a 12 Vdc source.

The layout is the following[image: As follows in the picture]

All the datasheets of the components I used can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0N9QgLumkRGS2YwUjFoQ3J0WUE&usp=drive_web)

Or [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=16816517668799049400)

The layout I used is pretty much similar to the one showed in the U1 datasheet,page 8 , fig. 2B.

I used a potentiometer instead of the R1 to obtain a variable voltage.

The input 12 Vdc is provided by a reliable and adjustable power source (set to 12 Volts and 1.5 Amp max. The source gives to the load the amount of power needed).

At first try the whole configuration worked,and I was able to obtain the desired output voltage. It was a little too much variable,from 280 to 320 approx, but I think that this is due to the high ESR of the output C4.

Then I was regulating the potentiometer a little randomly,and the configuration stopped working.

Now I am getting 28,7 Volt out,independently of the POT value.
Other Voltage values measured in the circuit:

V1(After Diode) 28,7

V1(Before Diode) 12

*On chip U1*

Vref 1,5

Vfb 0,2

V+ 12

Vext 0

Vcs 0

I tried to change one by one the following parts, U1 , Q1 , C4 , C1 with new ones.

I tried to elevate the value of C5 up to 330 pF.

I tried to remove C7 (which is not present in U1 datasheet).

The input voltage is fixed to 12 Volt,but the absorbed current is 0 Amps (the source as said can give up to 1,5 if requested by load).

Anyone has an idea of why the system is not working like in the beginning?
Thank you all in advance.

---

Datasheets:

- U1 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1253/0900766b81253c5c.pdf
- Q1 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/10ea/0900766b810ea1ab.pdf
- D1 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/11a6/0900766b811a65c3.pdf
- L1 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0fa5/0900766b80fa5686.pdf
- C1 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0027/0900766b800274c4.pdf
- C3 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1063/0900766b81063658.pdf
- R1 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0d81/0900766b80d81c44.pdf
- POT http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0fa5/0900766b80fa58ed.pdf
- R2 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/12cd/0900766b812cddf9.pdf
- C5 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/002d/0900766b8002d512.pdf
- C4 http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0ec9/0900766b80ec9186.pdf

Comment: I edited the link for the datasheets,now it should work. Yes the transistor is rated for 500V. I thought I might have broke it with the random adjustments on POT,but I changed it with a new one...

Comment: What output capacitors are you using?

Comment: I'm using a 2,2microFarad aluminium electrolitic capacitor,code UPW 2V 2R2 M PD , Nichicon. Rated for 350 V . You can now find the complete datasheet in main message (thanks to admin).